# Does this code go in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a fantasy racing prediction app. The goal is to predict the top ten finishers in a race. Correct predictions are awarded 3 points. Predictions that are 1 position off are awarded 2 points. Predictions that are 2 positions off are awarded 1 point.

I need to compare a User's Prediction to actual Results, subtracting the Prediction Position integer from the Result Position integer, and taking the absolute value. Then I can award 3,2,1, or 0 points accordingly. However I don't know where to put this code in my rails app.

My gut instinct is in the model, but I don't know where to start (I'm a beginner). I need some advice to steer me in the correct direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. The modle is where you want to encapsulate most of your business logic. The [Skinny Controller, Fat Model](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) post describes this in more detail, but your gut instinct is right. The model is the best place for that kind of complex logic.

You can encapsulate what you want to do in a method in your model, and if you use it in your controller or view it is just a call to `calculate_awarded_points` or whatever you decide to name it. Much easier to read than 10 extra lines of code in your controller that is not directly related to its purpose of connecting views and models.

Answer (score 0):

I would split this logic up into two places: the Model, and related Observers.

Store the actual point fields, and a reference to the related Result in the Prediction model and wire up an Observer to Result that calculates the Prediction scores when a Result is created.

More information: [ActiveRecord Observers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers)